# How to fetch large JSON response in android Sybase Unwired Platform

Tags: java, android, json, sybase

I know normal parsing in Android and Java .

But , here the case is bit different .

In cases when the default String (300) is set I can fetch JSON String with PAGESIZE being set as somewhat 2096 and I can generate code in Sybase.

But if I want to get data as large which is more than size 300 characters or if 300000 characters then the MBO hit can get it but not via code in Android .

In android code I get TRUNCATED data + some data of JSON fetched  after I hit for synchronize

So I need to know how can I fetch large JSON string as result via Android code
.

Kindly note : This question is for Sybase Android application development

A similar question has been posted in SAP forum but yet to answer 
http://scn.sap.com/thread/3738150

Comment: You are not even telling how you fetch small data. So how could we ever advise over adapting that for large data.

Comment: `I get a response in JSON and the whole string is passed as a only 1 result so I get Truncated JSON data from MBO after I syncronized it for hit `. To be honest i do not understand a word of this.

Comment: Edited . Please help

Comment: Can you use a streaming based JSON parser instead of a static "I have all the data just parse it" parser? Look into http://pivotallabs.com/parsing-json-data-efficiently-on-android-jsonreader/

Comment: @Kevin: Ahh !!! .. this is not even a question of parsing JSON . I can't fetch whole JSON string .. that's the current issue

Comment: You missed the point of my answer. There are two ways to get JSON, the first way your are using, all of it comes at once (if it will fit into single server response). The second way is via streaming. That gives it to you in chunks but you will get all of it if you process the chunks. You need to use the chunking method described in the link.

Comment: @Kevin : have you worked on SUP (Sybase Unwired Platform ) ?

Comment: No, I have never used SUP. I have had to deal with very large chunks of JSON data. When doing that I have used SAX style parsing to handle all the data and reassemble in on the Android side. It really sounds to me like this is the approach you need to take.

Answer (score 1):

for large data try to save your data in a database from the
beginning (it's a better practice), then deal with it using **SQLite**.

Answer (score 0):

Lets asume when you talk about fetching you mean fetching data from a server. 2 years ago the most robust approach was to use the gson library for android to parse the json string element by element.